# Frustrated with lack of response: Workbench not working for over a week now with no alternative

Tags: error-messages, workbench

It’s now getting highly frustrating with the  lack of ownership or response from anyone on such a core and critical tool used by developers and admins. I have reached out to Salesforce support been trying to see responses on this forum but nobody seems to know what’s going on. We cannot run SOQL scripts or anonymous scripts any longer. The alternates like VScode or DevConsole are clunky and limited compared to workbench.

The error im getting is UNKNOWN ERROR: read error on connection to ec2-34-194-152-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379

when I have to run a quick data extraction as simple as "select id from account" nothing comes close to the ease of workbench. Also when you have to update records like update [select id from account where owner.name='xyz']; work bench is the fastest and easiest tool available

I have tried multiple accounts and multiple devices and multiple networks but experience the same issue